# JQuery AJAX Header Authorization POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have to send **XML** to the server with **Authorization header** and it **MUST** be **POST**.

Now I have two options.

1. When I use dataType = 'jsonp' it always becomes GET instead of POST. Also my data is must be XML.

   ```
           var request = {};
           request.type = 'POST';
           request.contentType = 'application/jsonp; charset=utf-8';
           request.dataType = 'jsonp';
           request.data = JSON.stringify(this.data);
           request.url = this.url;
           request.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
               xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic ");
           };

           request.processData = false;
           $.ajax(request);
   ```
2. But without dataType = 'jsonp' I don't have Authentication header at all. The following code works only for Chrome.

   ```
       var request = {};
       request.type = 'POST';
       request.contentType = 'text/xml';
       request.dataType = 'xml';
       request.data = this.data;
       request.url = this.url;
       request.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic ");
       };

       request.processData = false;
       $.ajax(request);
   ```

Yes, I know that there are a lot of similar questions on StackOverflow and I've read dozens of them but still don't find the right answer.

Comment: So what have you tried that didn't work, post some code!

Answer (score 18):

Modify headers in the `beforeSend` method, for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        /* Authorization header */
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Utils.getUsernamePassword());
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mobile", "false");
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I already did this but when I set dataType = "json" it becomes GET.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I edited the answer and changed `type` to `method` in the ajax request. According to [jQuery.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), `type` is an alias for `method`. You should use `type` if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Comment: Is there a way to do basic authorization using `$.post()`?